# AWS Cognito Auth token - swift

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have successfully created a Cognito user pool and identity pool using aws amplify, and am able to use the documented process to login using the provided authUI. Once logged in, I can retrieve a jwt token via the provider response.... (not complete below so ignore any syntax errors)

```swift
AWSAuthUIViewController.presentViewController(
with: self.navigationController!, configuration: nil,
completionHandler: { (provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
    if error != nil {
       print("Error occurred: \(String(describing: error))")
    } else {
      // Sign in successful.
      print("sign in - token = \(provider.token())")
                                                
      var tokentask = provider.token()
      var output = tokentask.result
    }

})
```

I can then use that token (output) to authentication against an API gateway resource successfully. My problem is I cannot get the token at any other time. I cannot find the correct object to use to try to retrieve that token or cannot find the location where the token is cached so I can reuse it at other times in the app. Any assstance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i've managed to find out the best way -

```swift
AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.sharedInstance().getUserPool().token().continueWith { (AWSTask) -> Any? in
   if AWSTask.error == nil {
      print("Token \(String(describing: AWSTask.result))")
    }
        return nil
 }
```

This returns the token via awstask.